Tkinter Entry on Windows right shifted even with padx set to zero
I am running Tkinter on Widows in grid layout. The program has a mix of elements with and without columnspan. The elements that span across columns look as expected. But  elements (Entry and Button) without columnspan render shifted to the right. Setting padx = 0 does nothing.

window = Tk()
window.title('Password Manager')
window.config(padx=40, pady=40)

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
image_path = f'{current_dir}/logo.png'
logo_img = PhotoImage(file=image_path)
canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_img)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)


website_label = Label(text='Website:')
website_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

password_label = Label(text='Password:')
password_label.grid(column=0, row=3)

website_textbox = Entry(width=45)
website_textbox.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2)

password_textbox = Entry(width=21)
password_textbox.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=0)

generate_btn = Button(text='Generate Password', command=generate)
generate_btn.grid(column=2, row=3, padx=0)


window.mainloop()


Some of your widgets are less wide than the column containing them (due to the column containing another widget that is wider), and are being centered by default.  sticky='w' on both Entries would line up their left sides; perhaps you want to use `sticky='ew' to make them occupy the entire column.

You don't need to do with `pady.
Here Tkinter Grid is tutorial link.
You merely needed to add two columnspan=2 and three sticky='w'
Add this:

canvas.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=2)
website_textbox.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
password_textbox.grid(column=1, row=3, pady=0, sticky='w')
generate_btn.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky='w')

Screenshot:

